# Generate regular expression for given string and edit distance

Tags: php, mysql, regex, edit-distance

I have the problem that I want to match all strings in the database having a certain edit distance to a given string.

My idea was to generate a regular expression that would match all strings with edit distance `d` to string `s`.

So for example I want to generate a regex `r` for `d = 1` and `s = 'abc'` in the form of: `r = 'abc|.abc|.bc|a.c|ab.|abc.'` and so on. But I'm not sure if this is very efficient or are there already some good algorithms to that problem? I want to consider even character swaps in the edit distance. so `'acb'` should also be part of `r`. I want to realise it in PHP and then make an SQL query: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name RLIKE TheRegularExpression`.

Is it a good way to make it like that? Or what would you recommend?

Comment: If you want efficiency, first and foremost you should avoid applying a WHERE condition that can't be resolved using an index to all records in a table, unless that table is fairly small.

Comment: Also, consider that the length of the resulting pattern will be `O(nCd)`, where `n` is the length of the string, and `d` is your distance. This can potentially lead to very large patterns. For instance, for an `80`-character string, with a desired distance of `5`, you'd be sending a RE of about two-gigabytes to the database. (This is only considering character replacements, not transpositions.) However, if you're certain the strings will be short and/or the `d` either very small or very close to `n`, it might be feasible.

Comment: Another implication of this is that if the strings are entered by users, you need to make sure if the length is within a certain limit, otherwise you'd create a DoS hole. (As with any very, very inefficient algorithm with user-entered parameters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best thing to do is build up an iterative process for all the possibilities. In other words, something like this:

```
function findall($startString) {
    // create an array of all strings that are distance one away
    // each element would be $returnArray["abc"] = "abc";
}

$d = 2; // distance
$myArray[$startString] = $startString;

for($i = 0; $i < $d; $i++) {
    $newCombos = array_merge(array(), $myArray);
    foreach($myArray as $element) {
        $newCombos = array_merge($newCombos, findall($element));
    }
    $myArray = array_merge(array(), $newCombos);
}

$myRegex = implode("|", $myArray);
```

Comment: the only thing I noticed about the solution is, that the sql query is very long and slow for longer words and an edit distance higher than 2.

Comment: I actually think the Levenshtein function solution is probably better than mine (by enrico.bacis), you should check it out

Answer (score 5):

You can store a [Levenshtein function](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552) in Mysql. After that you can simply do the search like this:

```
mysql_qery("SELECT `term` FROM `words` WHERE levenshtein('$word', `term`) BETWEEN 0 AND '$d'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an implementation of [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (or something very similar). Here is a [function definition](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552) for use with MySQL.

Comment: It'd probably be more efficient to modify that algorithm to bail once the determined edit distance is over the required treshold, instead of needlessly computing the exact result.

Comment: thank you. the problem is, that on the server where I want to use it I don't have the rights to use stored functions and procedures...so I have to implement it with php though...